# Can you use the /spreadplayers command with armor stands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been trying to make a bomb using commands.

When the player uses the spawn egg I want it to summon like 10-20 invisible armor stands, then use `/spreadplayers` to spread them above ground and underground at a 10 block radius from the player. Afterwards, TNT is summoned at the armor stands and that makes the explosion. After that the armor stands are killed.

The problem is, I don't know if the `/spreadplayers` command even works with armor stands.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, [it turns out that you can use `/spreadplayers` with entities](http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/1uykaf/you_can_use_spreadplayers_with_e). This:

```
/spreadplayers 30 30 10 30 false @e[type=!Player]
```

Will spread any non-player entities. Using `@e[type=ArmorStand]` in that command instead will limit it to just your armour stands.

Answer (score 0):

```
/spreadplayers ~1 ~1 10 30 false @e[type=ArmorStand]
```

Answer (score 0):

`/spreadplayers ~1 ~1 10 11 @e[type=Armor_Stand]`
This answer updated for user112256 but now in 1.12.x, ArmorStand is now armor_stand.